# How does this heading area work on all browsers?

Tags: html, css, header

I just saw this browser here:

http://www.dietriffic.com/

Now, the green section at the top, no matter how I re-size my browsing window (Chrome), it manages to either fill it completely or just not show all of it.  How does it do this?  It is an image right?  They couldn't have prepared for every screen size could they?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't a HTML table with td set to colwidth of 100% and center aligned do this?

Comment: What I am saying is, the image doesn't distort but is somehow always the same width as the screen.

Comment: Right click on the page when it loads + "view source"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses a [horizontally- and vertically-repeated image](http://www.dietriffic.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_182/custom/images/green/header_area.png) across the width of the entire header:

[image]

and a centered, non-repeated, [mostly-transparent PNG](http://www.dietriffic.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_182/custom/images/green/header_inner.png) for that glow effect in the middle of the header:

[image]

Comment: As @Arun commented on your question, you only need to view the HTML and CSS source of that page to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Using Firebug:

The green box is

```
<div id="header_area" class="full_width">
```

It's using a repeating background image (the green) of size 50x50 that they use to fill the entire div with "tiles". The fact that the div always fits the browser viewport width is the class "full_width":

```
.full_width {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It's the `width: 100%` that does the scaling.

Apart from that, the centered text is not an image, it's real text. They achieve the centered alignment with

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

on the container element.